# Filter specific link from a feed with RegEx

Tags: regex, yahoo-pipes

Okay, so I have a RSS Feed. Every post contains multiple HTML-links. All of them are the same host (e.g. youtube.com) and than there's one with a different host.
I am trying to filter this one link.

So at the moment, i have a list of rules for the most common hosts (imgur, minus, tumblr, etc.), which looks like this:

```
(?i).*?href="(https?://[^"]*host1[^"]*).*
(?i).*?href="(https?://[^"]*host2[^"]*).*
(?i).*?href="(https?://[^"]*host3[^"]*).*
```

The problem is: there are alway links with unknown hosts.
So what I wanna do, is "blacklisting" the host from all the other links (which are all the same). I read about `(?!regex)` but it does not seem to work:

```
(?i).*?href="(https?://[^"]*(?!youtube)[^"]*).*
```

I hope you understand my problem and sorry for my (probably) bad english!

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: I´m using Regex on Yahoo Pipes...

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to want is the equivalent of "grep -v", but maybe you can't do that with Yahoo Pipes.  If you are going to use negative look ahead, your expression needs to define exactly where it is looking.

Let's start with something simple, "youtube" at the beginning of the string:

```
   $ echo youtubexyz | perl -lne  'print $1 if /(?!youtube)^(.+)/'
   $ echo ourtubexyz | perl -lne  'print $1 if /(?!youtube)^(.+)/'
   ourtubexyz
```

Now let's make a regular expression that targets some of the URLs you want to filter:

```
   $ echo www.youtube | perl -lne  'print $1 if /(www\.(?!youtube).+)/'
   $ echo www.ourtube | perl -lne  'print $1 if /(www\.(?!youtube).+)/'
   www.ourtube
```

You can continue to make your regular expression match more URLs and still exclude the "youtube" ones:

```
   $ echo www.youtube | perl -lne  'print $1 if /((?:www|\/\/)\.(?!youtube).+)/'
```

Note: I use capturing parentheses and 'print $1' to illustrate what is being matched.  You may not need to capture in your filter.